# django forms that refresh part of a page

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms

[django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) seem to be oriented for rerdirecting the user to a different page once the form has been submitted.
However I would to have a dynamically updating page where the form is inside a `<div></div>` while the output generated using the form information is in a second `<div></div>` on the same page. Once the form is submitted only the latter `div` should update. Something similar to the AJAX approach.

Is this possible using django forms? How?

Comment: Don't you mean d**i**v instead of d**e**v ?

Comment: Er yes, it's possible via the use of Ajax. What's your actual question?

Comment: I just don't see how Ajax and django forms fit together. I'm sure the answer is simple.

Comment: see [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431663/django-forms-and-ajax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need JavaScript. For example, with jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $('.other_div').html(data);
    })
})
```

Note: that won't work if your form contains file fields. In that case, rely on this plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ (function ajaxSubmit)

Comment: so the forms' response could simply be placed in the other div. How simple :)

Comment: Less is more, simple is better ;) You could also use a jQuery plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/. You will **need** it if your form contains file fields because ajax upload is a pain in the *****

Comment: considering the [form view pattern](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) how do I know if the returned result is the bounded form or the code that should be placed in the `other_div`?

Comment: In the $.post success function you could check if data contains a form tag. But if you have this question then the design smells. What's the code of your view ? What's the template ? I'm really wondering why should a view sometimes return a form, sometimes a result, when it would be simpler to just return both.

Comment: Most of the page is a form that contains various controls over a chart. I rather not refresh the entire page upon every form submission as the user does this many times, I rather only update the chart. As you can understand what I'm trying to do doesn't sit well with the [form view pattern in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) and I guess this is what I'm trying to figure out...

Comment: you helped me define [this more focused follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431663/django-forms-and-ajax)

Comment: Ok so if this answer did the job for this question, please mark as answered. It saves time when iterating over the list of unanswered questions in SO. TYIA :)